# Is there any way to set up developing environment of Hadoop using Intellij IDEA?

Tags: maven, hadoop, ant, intellij-idea, mapreduce

There are some articles for setting up the developing/building environment of Hadoop using eclipse, maven or ant.

However, there is no specific information about organizing developing environment using IntelliJ IDEA especially hadoop2.2.x version.

There is a page in HadoopWiki to configure those purposes, but those are not working.
[http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopUnderIDEA]

Is there anyone who develops and builds Hadoop on IntelliJ?
Then please let me know the way of configuring developing environment.

Thanks!